# SELECT field GROUP BY max(field) and GROUP BY other field MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, command-prompt

[I have record like this pic, PLEASE CLICK TO SHOW PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT3Yg.jpg)

[how to get like this pic, PLEASE CLICK TO SHOW PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aP1c.jpg)

create table query:

> create table lap ( no_faktur varchar(30) primary key, tgl_jual date,
>   kd_barang varchar(20), nm_barang varchar(100), harga_beli int (20),
>   harga_jual int(20), jum_jual int(10) );

insert table query:

> insert into lap values ('FJ-2013001','2013-10-01','B-001','laptop
>   Apple','500000','700000','2'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013002','2012-10-01','B-002','laptop
>   Apple','300000','500000','4'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013003','2013-10-03','B-001','laptop
>   Apple','500000','700000','1'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013004','2013-10-11','B-003','HDD 500
>   GB','700000','800000','1'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013005','2012-10-01','B-001','laptop
>   Apple','500000','700000','3'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013006','2013-10-04','B-004','MONITOR
>   14"','100000','800000','2'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013007','2013-02-01','B-001','laptop
>   Apple','700000','850000','4'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013008','2013-10-21','B-005','HDD 500
>   GB','800000','900000','3'); insert into lap values
>   ('FJ-2013009','2013-10-27','B-001','laptop
>   Apple','500000','700000','1');

I think like this:

> select
>   no_faktur,tgl_jual,kd_barang,nm_barang,harga_jual,jum_jual,sum(harga_jual*jum_jual) as total_jual from lap where month(tgl_jual)='10' and
>   year(tgl_jual)='2013' and jum_jual=(select max(jum_jual) from lap
>   group by kd_barang) order by total_jual desc;

But doesn't work because ***jum_jual** more than 1 rows.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: B-001 - Laptop - 4 and B-002 - Laptop - 4. Here kd_barang is unique. According to your expected output  4 should be listed one again you want unique kd_barang and max jum_jual too. Can you please check your expected output again? Thanks

Comment: thanks for ur suggest. I expect like pic without use query where no_faktur

Comment: sorry not clear what you meant. by the way if you still think your expected result that you want, then I can try to write sql query for you.

Comment: solved `select no_faktur,tgl_jual,kd_barang,nm_barang,harga_jual,sum(jum_jual) as jum_jual,sum(harga_jual*jum_jual) as total_jual
from lap where month(tgl_jual)='10' and year(tgl_jual)='2013'
group by kd_barang
order by total_jual desc;`

Comment: thanks for ur comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select no_faktur,tgl_jual,kd_barang,nm_barang,harga_jual,sum(jum_jual) as jum_jual,sum(harga_jual*jum_jual) as total_jual 
    from lap where month(tgl_jual)='10' and year(tgl_jual)='2013'
    group by kd_barang 
    order by total_jual desc;